# Laravel 'Whoops' error after view:clear route:clear

Tags: php, laravel

After running the commands

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

I am getting this generic Laravel error.

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

(Laravel was working up to this point. I was trying to fix an error with auth sessions.)

How can I bring my site back to life?

Comment: Have you checked `storage/logs/laravel.log`? What's the error?

Comment: @fubar is right, you need to check the laravel log for the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command:

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: That does not help. Is there anything else that needs to be done with this command?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Changing the app key will invalidate all user sessions and passwords.